# JBoss 6.1.1.EAP Module Deployment: Class not found

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss6.x

The structure is as follows:
Actually deployed module is EAR.
EAR contains WAR module, and WAR module contains another JAR module.
In this last JAR, there are some generated classes and their parent folder is also used as source folder. Its path is "target/generated-sources/java".
The problem that is killing me, is that the deployed application throws ClassNotFoundException on server start, and the classes in question are the generated ones.

Now the trick:
if I explicitly change the Deployment Assembly in WAR project in Eclipse not to contain JAR project as "project", but as an archive from the JAR's project "target" folder, JBoss sees the generated classes and starts.

This solution however works only until next eclipse maven project update, so manual edit of deployment assembly is not really a solution.

Any ideas how to deploy or reorganise packages correctly?

Comment: What happens if you build the EAR from a command line with `mvn clean package` and copy the resulting EAR file to JBoss? If that works OK then we can move on to your Eclipse issues

Comment: @SteveC I have the same issue, if I copy the EAR file to the deployment folder it starts. Could you elaborate on the Eclipse issues?

Comment: Do you have [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org) installed in Eclipse? These extensions know how to correctly deploy applications to WildFly/JBossAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seems I have found the solution.

I looked through the build-path of the mentioned JAR file and saw that the entry **Output folder** pointed to `target/test-classes`.

After changing this entry to `target/classes` the application deploys and starts without any missing generated classes.

Comment: Thanx! That worked! I also had to make sure to unselect "Update project configuration fom pom.xml" in Eclipse Maven update.

Comment: Keep in mind that unchecking "Update project configuration from pom.xml" may cause other pom changes to not affect you project configurations, automatically updated from m2e and m2e-wtp plugins as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Expand the 'target' folder of your maven project inside Eclipse (Project Explorer View);
2. Refresh it (F5);
3. Right click on your project on 'Servers' tab, then select "Full Publish";
4. Start your JBoss.

I had to enforce the JBoss Tool "Full Publish" to get an updated version of my target folder by Refreshing it manually on eclipse.

I don't know why but sometimes the Publishing from maven projects (even Full Publishes) do not copy classes from the target Project as it is in the file system. Maybe it's using some outdated memory info or some cache...

Anyway, this is what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

After an update to Eclipse 4.15 and JBoss tools I got this problem too.

My solution: project -> properties -> Java Build Path --> Source

There my Output folder from my source was linked to project/target/classes, I changed this to project/target/project-projectversion/WEB-INF/classes

When I looked into the standalone JBoss folder I saw the folder structure of my source, but the classes where missing, when I changed the output folder the classes pop up and everything worked like before.

I am pretty sure the update made the problems.